# How to add link in sidebar of ant design (version >=4.20.0)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, antd

I searched and tried different methods to apply links in the sidebar of ant design. But in vain.
In the last version, we were applying links like this

```
<Menu.SubMenu key="SubMenu" icon={<SettingOutlined />}>
  <Menu.Item key="two" icon={<AppstoreOutlined />}>
    <Link to="">Navigation Two</Link>
  </Menu.Item>
</Menu.SubMenu>
```

But now they have changed it to function-based. Something like this

```
<Menu
  mode="inline"
  openKeys={openKeys}
  onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
  style={{ width: 256 }}
  items={items}
/>
```

Now I tried a few methods to apply links to code. But they are not working properly. If anybody can help then, please help.

antd link:https://ant.design/components/menu/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well what you can do is add navigation in label key in items array and then your code will be working same as before

```
const items: MenuProps['items'] = [
  {
    label: 'Navigation One',
    key: 'mail',
    icon: <MailOutlined />,
  },
  {
    label: (
      <a href="https://ant.design" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        Navigation Two
      </a>
    ),
    key: 'alipay',
  },
];
```

Comment: Thank you, man. The answer was there this whole time but I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

### Use this react component

- Add `<Link />` component
- Displaying 3 levels
- Can check permission
- Full custom setup

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { HomeOutlined, SafetyOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Menu, Layout } from 'antd';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from 'context/auth-context'
import { PrivateLayoutContext } from 'context/private-layout-context'
const { Sider } = Layout;


function LeftSideBar() {
    const { permissions } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const { leftSideBarCollapsed } = useContext(PrivateLayoutContext);

    const items = [
        {
            label: 'Home',
            path: '/',
            key: 'home',
            icon: <HomeOutlined />,
        },
        {
            label: 'Access Control',
            key: 'access-control',
            icon: <SafetyOutlined />,
            children: [
                {
                    label: 'User',
                    path: '/access-control/user',
                    key: 'user',
                    permission: 'user list',
                },
                {
                    label: 'Role',
                    path: '/access-control/role',
                    key: 'role',
                    permission: 'role list',
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'Configuration',
            key: 'configuration',
            icon: <SafetyOutlined />,
            children: [
                {
                    label: 'Inventory',
                    key: 'inventory',
                    children: [
                        {
                            label: 'Inventory 1',
                            path: '/configuration/inventory',
                            key: 'inventory-1',
                            permission: 'inventory list',
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Inventory 2',
                            path: '/configuration/inventory-2',
                            key: 'inventory-2',
                            permission: 'inventory list',
                        },
                    ]

                },
                {
                    label: 'Customer',
                    path: '/configuration/customer',
                    key: 'customer',
                }
            ]
        },
    ]

    const onClick = (e) => {
        console.log('click', e);
    };


    return (
        <Sider trigger={null} collapsible collapsed={leftSideBarCollapsed} >

            {/* This menu is designed to be used for displaying 3 levels */}
            <Menu
                onClick={(e) => onClick(e)}
                style={{
                    height: '100vh',
                }}
                mode="vertical"
                items={
                    // level 1 = root level
                    items.map((l1_item, index) => {
                        // console.log(l1_item?.permission, permissions, permissions?.includes(l1_item?.permission));
                        return {
                            ...l1_item,
                            label: <Link to={l1_item?.path}>{l1_item?.label}</Link>,
                            // level 2
                            children: l1_item?.children?.map((l2_item, l2_index) => {
                                // if (l2_item) has permission then check permission exist in permissions array, otherwise return
                                let return_status = 0;
                                if (l2_item?.permission) {
                                    if (permissions?.includes(l2_item?.permission)) {
                                        return_status = 1;
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    return_status = 1;
                                }
                                return return_status && {
                                    ...l2_item,
                                    label: <Link to={l2_item?.path}>{l2_item?.label}</Link>,
                                    // level 3
                                    children: l2_item?.children?.map((l3_item, l3_index) => {
                                        // if (l3_item) has permission then check permission exist in permissions array, otherwise return
                                        let return_status = 0;
                                        if (l3_item?.permission) {
                                            if (permissions?.includes(l3_item?.permission)) {
                                                return_status = 1;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            return_status = 1;
                                        }
                                        return return_status && {
                                            ...l3_item,
                                            label: <Link to={l3_item?.path}>{l3_item?.label}</Link>
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
            >


            </Menu>

        </Sider>
    )
};
export default LeftSideBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can address this issue by utilizing a recursive function that enriches the menu items with links attached to their labels. This approach also makes use of the `Link` component from `react-router-dom`.

```js
import { MenuProps } from "antd/lib/menu";
import { ItemType, MenuItemGroupType, MenuItemType, SubMenuType } from "antd/lib/menu/hooks/useItems";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export const addLinksToMenuItemLabels = (items?: MenuProps["items"]): MenuProps["items"] =>
  items?.map((item) => {
    const { key, label } = (item as MenuItemType | SubMenuType | MenuItemGroupType) || {};
    if (!key || !label) return item;
    const { children } = (item as SubMenuType | MenuItemGroupType) || {};
    return {
      ...item,
      label: <Link to={`${paths[key]}`}>{label}</Link>,
      children: addLinksToMenuItemLabels(children),
    } as ItemType;
  });
```

In this example, the link's destination path is extracted from an object that associates a path with each menu key.